# Usar caracteres especiales en <option>

Tags: php, html

No sé si es posible pero necesito usar caracteres especiales en un `<option>` que tiene acentos. El valor del option lo recojo en una variable denominada `$genero`. El ejemplo que estoy intentando es el siguiente:

```
<option name="Acci&oacute;n" value="Acci&oacute;n" <?php if ($genero == 'Acci&oacute;n') {echo 'selected';} ?>>Acción</option>
$genero = isset($_GET['Genero']) ? $_GET['Genero'] : 'todos';
```

Sin embargo, no sé si debido a PHP o por HTML, en vez de recibir el valor de `Acci&oacute;n` recibo el de `Acción`, con lo cual la búsqueda en la base de datos es nula.

Comment: Al generarse la pagina el navegador convierte la codificacion de los caracteres especiales a estos por lo que por eso recibes Acción

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es el navegador lo está decodificando, pero podrías usar la función `htmlentities()`

Un ejemplo sencillo:

```
<?php
    $var = "Acci&oacute;n";
    $x = htmlentities($var);
    echo $x;
?>
```

El resultado que nos dará es lo siguiente:

```
Acci&oacute;n
```

Más info: http://php.net/manual/es/function.html-entity-decode.php